# Couldn't initialize spark context

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to initialize Spark Context variable in Python.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

But I am getting following error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:373)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
>           at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
>           at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have looked around for solution but not did not get exact solution. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Setting **SPARK_LOCAL_IP** environment variable to **localhost** solved my error.

Comment: That did it in my case! Just hack `export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost` into your terminal and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have this set?

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```

Also just to be sure, add the path to the py4j zip (mine is py4j-0.10.1-src.zip) in the spark directory as:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try mentioning master as "local[*]" instead of just "local".