# Spark on Win10 installation erroring out at None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've been struggling a lot to get Spark running on my Windows 10 device lately, without success. I merely want to try out Spark and to be able to follow tutorials, thus I don't currently have access to a cluster to connect to. In order to install Spark, I completed the following steps, [based on this tutorial](https://medium.com/i-want-to-be-the-very-best/installing-apache-spark-on-windows-10-ce1c45de35ab):

- I installed the Java JDK and placed it to `C:\jdk`. The folder has `bin`, `conf`, `include`, `jmods`, `legal`, and `lib` folders inside.
- I installed the Java runtime environment and placed it to `C:\jre`. This one has `bin`, `legal`, and `lib` folders inside.
- I downloaded [this folder](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip) and placed the `winutils.exe` into `C:\winutils\bin`.
- I created a `HADOOP_HOME` user environmental variable and set it to `C:\winutils`
- I opened the Anaconda Prompt and installed PySpark by `conda install pyspark` to my base environment.
- Upon successful installation, I opened a new prompt and typed `pyspark` to verify the installation. This should give a Spark welcome screen. Instead, I got the following long error message though:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/12/05 12:22:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/12/05 12:22:47 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Users\lazarea\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1573, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\lazarea\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I looked around on Stackoverflow for similar issues and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535236/couldnt-initialize-spark-context). This has a similar error message. Yet, the provided solution, i.e. setting the `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` user environment variable to `localhost` didn't solve the issue, the same error message persists when typing `pyspark` to Anaconda Prompt.

**Note #1**, this might be relevant: When typing `pyspark` to the command line, no output is provided. Instead, Windows opens the Microsoft Store by default.

**Note #2**: I tried coding directly in Python and see if there's any more hint from that side. I ran the following snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sampleApp').getOrCreate()
```

which returned a similar error message as the one above, with some more, potentially useful information:

```
An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
(in unnamed module @0x776b83cc) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer
(in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch
to unnamed module @0x776b83cc
```

**Note #3**: When opening the command line and typing `spark-shell`, the following error is output:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x3c947bc5) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x3c947bc5
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
  ... 55 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
```

Please help me successfully launch Spark because I fail to understand what I might be missing at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I succeeded so let me share what I learned for future reference in case anyone else would later on struggle with Apache Spark installation as well. There are three crucial aspects when installing Apache Spark on a Windows 10 machine.

1. **Make sure you have Java 8 installed!** Many of us fall into the trap of downloading the now-default Java 17 which is not supported by Apache Spark. There is an option to choose between either Java 8 or Java 11 but based on the discussion [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733312/where-is-jre-11), I concluded that for my quick POC examples it's not worth all that trouble with Java 11 JDK and JRE, hence I went with the Java 8 for which both JDK and JRE were easily downloadable from the Oracle website. Note that the later version you choose, the more secure it will be, so for anything more serious I'd probably opt for the Java 11.
2. **Move the newly installed Java folders to C drive.** Create a `C:\jdk` folder for the Java 8 JDK and `C:\jre` for he Java 8 JRE. Then, there won't be a need for a JAVA_HOME environmental variable since they are both right in the base of the C drive.
3. **Use an older version of Spark!** As it turned out, the latest stable release, 3.2.0 from October 2021 that is currently offered on the Apache Spark website has been repeatedly reported to provide such and other similar issues when initializing the Spark Context. As such, I tried rolling back to a previous version. Specifically, I downloaded Apache Spark version 3.0.3 released in June 2021 and pointed the `SPARK_HOME` environmental variable to the newly extracted folder at: `C:\Spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7`

After all these modifications, I closed all command line windows, opened a fresh one, ran `spark-shell` and finally I am getting the so much sought after welcome screen of Spark:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.3
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_301)
```