# PySpark 3.2.1 - basic actions crashing on very small RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am testing simple PySpark functions locally in JupyterLab using Python 3.9.10 in a conda-forge environment on Windows 10.

Setup:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("PySpark_Test") 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) # Default SparkContext

# Verify SparkContext
print(sc)

# Print the Spark version of SparkContext
print("The version of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is:", sc.version)

# Print the Python version of SparkContext
print("The Python version of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is:", sc.pythonVer)

# Print Master of SparkContext: URL of the cluster or “local” string to run in local mode 
print("The master of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is:", sc.master)

# Print name of SparkContext
print("The appName of Spark Context is:", sc.appName)
```

Output:

```
<SparkContext master=local[4] appName=PySpark_Test>
The version of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is: 3.2.1
The Python version of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is: 3.9
The master of Spark Context in the PySpark shell is: local[4]
The appName of Spark Context is: PySpark_Test
```

---

```
# Create a Python list of numbers from 1 to 10
numb = [*range(1, 11)]

# Load the list into PySpark  
numbRDD = sc.parallelize(numb)

numbRDD.collect()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

```
type(numbRDD)
```

Output:

```
pyspark.rdd.RDD
```

---

```
cubedRDD = numbRDD.map(lambda x: x**3)
type(cubedRDD)
```

Output:

```
pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
```

---

Everything above works fine.

I am getting crashing when I run almost any action on this very small cubedRDD.

These actions will crash:

- cubedRDD.collect()
- cubedRDD.first()
- cubedRDD.take(2)
- cubedRDD.count()

Error excerpt:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 3 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0
> in stage 8.0 (TID 30) (10.0.0.236 executor driver):
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> ...

> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
> ...

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
> ...

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: Java 8 Update 321

Comment: And JDK 8 Update 311.  Both JRE and JDK installed to c:\

Comment: That should be okay, although you only need the JDK. You might want to try java 11 instead though

Comment: Thank you. I removed JRE 8 and JDK 8 and installed JDK 11.0.13 at c:\jdk, and still have the crashing.

Comment: I had installed JDK/JRE 8 because of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233918/spark-on-win10-installation-erroring-out-at-none-org-apache-spark-api-java-javas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the **PYSPARK_PYTHON** SYSTEM environment variable (user-level variable will also work) to point to the python.exe in my conda-forge environment (Miniconda).

PYSPARK_PYTHON = C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\envs\spark39\python.exe

I finally found [this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/configuration.html#environment-variables) in the PySpark docs that told me about that env variable.  No other tutorial or installation instructions for PySpark I have found mentioned that variable.

I also turned off the App Execution Aliases for "App Installer" for python.exe and python3.exe.  I only have Python installed via Miniconda.

Everything is running fine with jdk1.8.0_321 installed.

Side note: to get Spark Dataframe **write** operations to work (unrelated to this thread), set HADOOP_HOME **SYSTEM** variable to C:\winutils and SYSTEM PATH to include %HADOOP_HOME%\bin.  That bin directory should hold [Hadoop native libraries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems) for your version of HADOOP.  For Pyspark 3.2.1 from conda-forge, I used hadoop.dll and winutils.exe from [here](https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.3.1/bin).

Comment: Btw, HADOOP_HOME should actually be pointing at the Hadoop directory, not winutils. Also, JAVA_HOME is "automatically" computed in the spark-submit command

Comment: I don't have HADOOP installed, so winutils.exe file from [here](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip) is all I need.

Comment: If you downloaded Spark from the official website, it comes with Hadoop.

Comment: It does. Spark requires the Hadoop SDK to run